# Why $\mathbb E[X_i^2\mathbb E[B_{t_i}-B_{t_i-1}\mid\mathcal F_{t_i-1}]]=\mathbb E[X_i^2]\mathbb E[B_{t_i}-B_{t_i-1}\mid \mathcal F_{t_i-1}]$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(B_t)_t$ a brownian motion adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_t$, and $X_i$ a r.v. $\mathcal F_{t_i-1}$-measurable s.t. $\mathbb E[X_i^2]<\infty$.  Why $$\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E[X_i^2(B_{t_i}-B_{t_i-1})\mid \mathcal F_{t_i-1}]\Big]=\mathbb E\Big[X_i^2\mathbb E[B_{t_i}-B_{t_i-1}\mid\mathcal F_{t_i-1}]\Big]=\mathbb E[X_i^2]\mathbb E[B_{t_i}-B_{t_i-1}\mid \mathcal F_{t_i-1}]\ \ ?$$
The first equality comme from the fact that $X_i^2$ is $\mathcal F_{t_i-1}$ measurable. But I don't understand the second one.

Comment: is $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ an arbitrary filtration or maybe is it the  filtration generated by the brownian motion?

Comment: Are you sure that the last conditional expectation is conditional?

Comment: @zap: It's what I wrote in my course, but I may be made a mistakes.

Comment: @zap: for $\mathcal F_t$, like I wrote in my post, is adapted at $B_t$

Comment: The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]$ can be pulled out simply because it is constant: $$\mathbb{E}[B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}] = \mathbb{E}[B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}].$$ In that sense, the notation $\mathbb{E}[B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}} \mid \mathcal{F}_{t_{i-1}}]$ is misleading.